# Java 8 Collector with string concatenating

Tags: java, java-stream

I have this class:

```
class Pair {
    public String name;
    public int age;
}
```

And a list:

```
List<Pair> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.add(new Pair("One", 25));
list.add(new Pair("Two", 18));
list.add(new Pair("Three", 18));
list.add(new Pair("Four", 10));
```

Where `Pair` just contains two values, a `String` and an `int`.

I want to group this data by its `age` value, but also concatenate the `name`. In final I want to obtain a `Map<Integer, String>` like this:

```
25 - One
18 - TwoThree
10 - Four
```

I tried this :

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Pair::getValue, /* Collectors.??? */));
```

There are methods like `summingInt`, but can't find anything for `String` values.

I see there's a `Collectors.reducing` method, I'm guessing maybe we can use it, not sure how to though.

Is there an elegant way to do it with build in `Collectors` or I have to make my own ?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for `Collectors.joining`.

Comment: How do I specify in  ``Collectors.joining`` that I want to concatenate ``name`` value ? As far as I know you can apply it for list of ``String``, but I have here a list of ``Pair``

Comment: `Collectors.mapping(Pair::getName, Collectors.joining())`.

Comment: Aha, ``Collectors.mapping`` is the key here). Now it works, Thanks.

Comment: btw that `Collectors#joining` is implemented with `StringJoiner`. *finally* a class in java-8 for joining Strings ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `Collectors.mapping(Pair::getName, Collectors.joining())`.  `joining` deals with the strings, and `mapping` extracts them from the pair objects.